# How to add a bracket above a gather environment?

Tags: align, amsmath, brackets, braces, mathjax

I would like to turn this :

```latex
$$
\begin{gather}
\overbracket{\text{1 2}}^{\text{Basic idea}} & 
\overbracket{\text{3 4}}^{\text{Contrasting idea}} \\
\underbracket{\text{5 6}}_{\text{Basic idea}} & 
\underbracket{\text{7 8}}_{\text{Cadence}}
\end{gather}
$$
```

[image]

Into this :

[image]

I tried the following :

```latex
$$
\begin{gather}
\begin{aligned}
\overbracket{\kern5em}^{\text{anticipation}}
\end{aligned}\\
\overbracket{\text{1 2}}^{\text{Basic idea}} & 
\overbracket{\text{3 4}}^{\text{Contrasting idea}} \\
\underbracket{\text{5 6}}_{\text{Basic idea}} & 
\underbracket{\text{7 8}}_{\text{Cadence}}
\end{gather}
$$
```

But it's not centered as desired :

[image]

Comment: do not put `gather` inside `$$` (in fact don't use `$$` at all in latex)

Comment: you shouldput thealigned in the overbracket (not a kern)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle : I'm using mathjax plugin for Obsidian, a text editor, not sure if other syntax are offered.

I'm not sure what you mean by put the aligned in the overbracket : could you clarify please ?

Comment: Note that purely mathjax questions are off topic here, I just answered assuming that you were using latex, but you may find it works in mathjax (although that doesn't actually use tex at all)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need some work to make the brackets the same width.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\newcommand{\overunderbrack}[3]{{\overbracket{\underbracket{#3}_{#2}}^{#1}}}

\begin{document}

\[
\newcommand{\zw}[1]{\text{\makebox[0pt]{#1}}}% just for this display
\overbrace{
  \settowidth{\dimen0}{$\scriptstyle\text{Basic idea}$}
  \mathmakebox[\dimen0]{\overunderbrack{\zw{Basic idea}}{\zw{Basic idea}}{
    \begin{matrix} 1 & 2 \\ 5 & 6 \end{matrix}
  }}
  \quad
  \settowidth{\dimen0}{$\scriptstyle\text{Contrasting idea}$}
  \mathmakebox[\dimen0]{\overunderbrack{\zw{Contrasting idea}}{\zw{Cadence}}{
    \begin{matrix} 3 & 4 \\ 7 & 8 \end{matrix}
  }}
}^{\text{Anticipation}}
\]

\[
\overbrace{
  \settowidth{\dimen0}{$\scriptstyle\text{Contrasting idea}$}
  \mathmakebox[\dimen0]{\overunderbrack{\zw{Basic idea}}{\zw{Basic idea}}{
    \begin{matrix} 1 & 2 \\ 5 & 6 \end{matrix}
  }}
  \quad
  \mathmakebox[\dimen0]{\overunderbrack{\zw{Contrasting idea}}{\zw{Cadence}}{
    \begin{matrix} 3 & 4 \\ 7 & 8 \end{matrix}
  }}
}^{\text{Anticipation}}
\]

\end{document}
```

In the second display, the left part is set to a box as wide as the right part, take your pick. This is achieved by enclosing the `\overunderbrack` construction in a box of the desired width, but with zero width, as far as TeX is concerned, labels.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Something like

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}

\[
\overbrace{
\overbracket{
\underbracket{\begin{matrix}
1&2\\
5&6
\end{matrix}}_{\text{Basic idea}}}
^{\text{Basic idea}} 
\;
\overbracket{
\underbracket{\begin{matrix}
3&4\\
7&8
\end{matrix}}_{\text{Cadence}}}
^{\text{Contrasting idea}} 
}^{\text{Anticipation}}
\]

\end{document}
```

Comment: But the top square brackets should be the same width as the ones on the bottom.